# Child element displayed in incorrect location when parent element has a 2D transform

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

Elements with the CSS property 'transform' doesn't like embedded elements with the property 'position: absolute' and it is driving me crazy!!!

When clicking on a menu item, a content div appears. When there is no 2D transform on the parent, it is in the right place, but is displayed to the far right when hovering over its parent.

Is there a way to fix this?

note: I can't move the embedded element (.floater) outside the box because it's included within an ng-repeat (repeater from AngularJs)

(click and hover in and out to see what i mean)

here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbgd4cdj/2/).

css(3):

```
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:100px auto;
}
.box:hover {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.box p {
    padding: 10px;
    background: gray;
}
.floater {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    top:126px;
    left:520px;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual issue is.  "Doesn't like" isn't very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

When an element has a 2D transform, its child elements seem to treat it as if it were `position: relative;` or `position: static`.

All you need to do it make the `.box` `position: relative;` so the behaviour remains consistent, and then position the `.floater` relative to the box.

So change `.box` to

```
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:100px auto;
    position: relative; // this is the added line
}
```

And change `.floater`'s left and top like so

```
.floater {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    top: 0; // changed this
    left: 250px; // changed this.
}
```